# using google signing in resulting the exception PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gradle

I a trying to add a sign in with google button but it still now working, actually it is not returning from the line

```
 await googleSignIn.signIn();
```

resulting exception

E/flutter (12458): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

here is my controller code

```
static Future<User> signInWithGoogle({@required BuildContext context}) async {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User user;
  log("first of all ");
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  log('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ after await ');
  if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
    log('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ nor null ');
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );
    try {
      final UserCredential userCredential =
          await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      user = userCredential.user;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        //
      } else if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {
        //
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ...
    }
  }
  return user;
}
```

and here is the button on press action:

```
OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    setState(() {
      _isSigningIn = true;
    });
    AuthController.signInWithGoogle(context: context);
    setState(() {
      _isSigningIn = false;
    });
  },
),
```

and the android/app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1"
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
}
```

and the android/build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}
```

and the android/gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

I have tried a lot of ways to call the firebase authenticator but all the ways ends up with the same error and same result that it still in the await returning the same exception ... thanks for your help in advance

Comment: is google signin provider enabled and did you added sha keys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the Google provider was not enables as commented by raghav042 so I enabled it then i added the SHA-1 fingerprint to the firebase project and add the new google services file to my android app then the error have gone !!... thanks a lot